# Save from Vector of int to 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

I have this vector of int from which I have to save the values to a 2D array.I though it was straight forward, but it seems that for `i+j`, when `j` becomes `0`, the next integer to be saved is saved over the last one.They overlap. Can you please tell me how to fix it ? Here is the code:

---

```
vector<int> temp_table;//filled it in previous code, just for info
int** arr_table =new int* [number_of_states];
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_states; i++)
{
arr_table[i] = new int[alphabet.size()];
}

for(int i=0;i<number_of_states;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<alphabet.size();j++)
    {
        arr_table[i][j]=temp_table.at(i+j);//This is where the overlapping occurs 
         //when j=0.How to fix it to save the correct data?
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<number_of_states;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<alphabet.size();j++)
    {
        cout<<arr_table[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your index into `temp_table` will be something like `(i * alphabet.size()) + j`. It depends on how the data is stored in the 1d vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want scale your `i` indexing by `alphabet.size()` to take into account the rows that have already been added:

```
for(int i=0;i<number_of_states;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<alphabet.size();j++)
        arr_table[i][j]=temp_table.at(i * alphabet.size() + j);
```